Consistent generic sorting with XSLT
My input is some unsorted XML, and I want to sort it - first alphabetically by I'm running into an issue when attempting to sort XML files with XSL. I want to sort through any number of nested nodes, first alphabetically by node, and then alphabetically by the text values as needed.
I'm having issues with "list" items consistently ordering. In my example below, it seems that sometimes it will order the two book items based on the title, whereas other times it will be done based on the author. I assume this has something to do with how the XML is ordered on input, but I have no knowledge of how this will come in.
I don't care which book item comes first, only that it happens with consistency. Also, I want this to work generically. The list could be movies instead, or could be nested much deeper.
Example Input:
<root>
   <nodeA>text</nodeA>
   <nodeC>text</nodeC>
   <nodeB>text</nodeB>
   <bookList>
      <book>
         <title>ABC</title>
         <author>John</author>
      </book>
      <book>
         <title>XYZ</title>
         <author>Dan</author>
      </book>
   </bookList>         
</root>

Stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
         <xsl:sort select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Example Ouptut #1:
<root>
   <bookList>
      <book>
         <author>John</author>
         <title>ABC</title>
      </book>
      <book>
         <author>Dan</author>
         <title>XYZ</title>
      </book>
   </bookList>  
   <nodeA>text</nodeA>
   <nodeB>text</nodeB>
   <nodeC>text</nodeC>      
</root>

Example Ouptut #2:
<root>
   <bookList>
      <book>
         <author>Dan</author>
         <title>XYZ</title>
      </book>
      <book>
         <author>John</author>
         <title>ABC</title>
      </book>
   </bookList>  
   <nodeA>text</nodeA>
   <nodeB>text</nodeB>
   <nodeC>text</nodeC>      
</root>

As mentioned above, I'm fine with either output but I need it to work consistently with any order of input.

You cannot get two different outputs with the same XML input and the same XSLT. Something is different, most likely the order of title and author within a book. Your stylesheet sorts the books by their string-value, which is a concatenation of the two, in their original order. I am not sure what exactly you want to happen and how generic you need this to be.

Note also that the stylesheet does not produce either one of the outputs you show because author will always come before title. And you have an error in the stylesheet's namespace declaration.

And what kind of sorting would you expect for mixed contents like XHTML or Docbook or TEI?

@michael.hor257k I know but the point is that I don't know the order of the input. All I know is the structure of the xml.
My mistake on the output - this isn't my actual use case, so I just tried to create a generic example. I want the two books to be ordered the same regardless of the ordering in the input. I'm not sure what you mean by "concatenation of the two". The two fields (title and author)?

Yes. You can see the definition of string-value of an element here: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#element-nodes. If you know the structure of the input XML, then you can sort the books explicitly by author, then by title (or vice-versa, if you prefer). I doubt you will find a feasible generic solution to accommodate any XML input. Certainly not with XSLT 1.0, which is what you seem to be using.

The problem seems to be that the second sort in your xslt still uses the complete content before the first sort.
You could try a pipeline approach where you first sort the xml by name of elements and the following transformation by the content of that first element.
In the FIRST xslt you could do something like this:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="step1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

Using the result-xml of the first step in this SECOND xslt:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="step2"/>
  </xsl:template>
      
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="step2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="step2">
        <xsl:sort select="*[1]/text()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

If you are able to using xslt 3.0 you could combine these two xslt's in one xslt like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="step1" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="step2" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="step1" as="document-node()">
      <xsl:document>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1"/>
      </xsl:document>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$step1" mode="step2"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="step1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="step1">
        <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="step2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="step2">
        <xsl:sort select="*[1]/text()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

